# What's suggested approach to create UI similar to Facebook News Feed?

Tags: ios, facebook, user-interface

What's better approach to develop UI/UX similar to facebook new feed and attached Image. 
[image: iOS Feed]

I would like to make it as an Native app. If there is any framework available then I'm willing to use that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic

This open source code available for this app.

This app similar to Instagram app. This shows social feeds of images shared by user.

They have custom TableViewCell and TableViewHeaders.

Try this. It might help you.

Comment: Also review the "Activity Stream" UI pattern at http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/ActivityStream